# how to display info in a listbox instead of edit box?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, listbox, editbox

i want to create a client server program in mfc
i found some really good source code from this website: http://www.softwareandfinance.com/Visual_CPP/TCP_Client_Server.html

ok can someone help me display the information in a listbox instead of the edit box?

here's the code to process the client:

```
static void f(void *p)
{
    CSocketTestServerDlg *pDlg = reinterpret_cast<CSocketTestServerDlg*>(p);
    pDlg->ProcessClientRequest();
}

void CSocketTestServerDlg::ProcessClientRequest()
{
    SOCKADDR_IN clientaddr;
    struct hostent *hostentry;
    int len = sizeof(clientaddr);
    SOCKET clientsocket = accept(m_serversocket, (sockaddr*)&clientaddr, &len);

    if(len == -1)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("Error accpeting the client socket");
    }
    else
    {
        char *p = inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr);
        int portno = ntohs(clientaddr.sin_port);
        // int inet_pton(int af, const char *restrict src, void *restrict dst);

        char rbuf[1024];
        recv(clientsocket, rbuf, 1024, 0);
        for(int i = 1024; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            if(rbuf[i] == '\n' && rbuf[i - 1] == '\r')
            {
                rbuf[i-1] = '\0';
                break;
            }
        }


        CString strRecvData;

        strRecvData.Format("%s\r\n%s %d\r\n%s\r\n\r\n", (const char*)CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"), p, portno, rbuf);
        m_recvData += strRecvData;
        m_bRefershData = true;
        strcat(rbuf, "\r\n");
        send(clientsocket, rbuf, 1024, 0);
        closesocket(clientsocket);
    }
}
```

so how can i just get the ip address from the client to display in a list box? i don't need all the other information

Comment: What's the question? How to display info on a ListBox or how to get just the IP address?

Comment: i just want the ip address to display in the listbox. i don't want all the other information

Comment: Isn't the IP address in `clientaddr.sin_addr`? I haven't worked much with sockets, but that's what I gather from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zx63b042(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: the code is already getting the ip address. i just really want to know how to display stuff in the listbox instead of the editbox. this line displays everything: strRecvData.Format("%s\r\n%s %d\r\n%s\r\n\r\n", (const char*)CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S"), p, portno, rbuf);

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already have the IP as a string in `p`, don't you?

You could create a CString from it to avoid UNICODE problems. Then use CListBox::AddString to output your string:

```
char *p = inet_ntoa(clientaddr.sin_addr);

CString str(p);

//CListBox listbox;

listbox.AddString(str);
```

Comment: Then maybe you have to show some more code. I mean, if ´str´ is holding the IP address string (it is, isn't it?), but after AddString nothing shows, something must be wrong somewhere else, as in the "wiring" of the dialog.

Comment: ok i edited the code i first posted. that is the original code. i haven't changed anything

Comment: There's no lisbox in that code. How have you created the listbox? Or have you even created it? You are asking about putting text in a listbox and showing code that works on an editctrl.

Comment: i just said that is the original code. but yes i have created the listbox. i'm using a mfc dialog program so i inserted the listbox

Comment: Well, I don't know what you are doing, but I've downloaded the source code you linked to, I've created a listbox next to the edit control in the dialog, Ive created a control variable for the listbox, and then, just below m_recvData += strRecvData, I've added c_MyListBox.AddString(CString(p)); and it works fine.